# Calculating $g$-force in between planets

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

The g-force is given by $1 + \frac{a}{g}$. The question is that a rocket is accelerating from between Mars AND Juptier at 26.95m/s. The astronaut in focus is 60kg (irrelevant I believe).

Using this, I need to calculate the g-force. I have the correct answer on the sheet - 2.75.

Using $1 + \frac{a}{g}$:

$1 + \frac{26.95}{9.81}$

I get a value of 3.75

I seem to be off by 1.

Can someone show me were I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the 1 in you formula comes from the attraction of the earth.
$${g-force} = \frac{\sum a }{g}$$

So normally on earth you would have, the accelerations coming from the earth, and the rocket:

$$\sum a = g + a_{rocket}$$

Thus the g-force would be:

$${g-force} = \frac{g + a_{rocket} }{g}=1+\frac{a_{rocket}}{g}$$

However, when we are in space, far away from the earth, there is no gravitation coming from the earth (or at least very small)

Therefore we have:

$${g-force} = \frac{0+a_{rocket} }{g}=0+\frac{a_{rocket}}{g}$$

Please always check if formula's are valid for your specific case, it is vital for reaching the right answer.